# ‘Remember this!!!’ in context

Tags: idioms, expressions

While watching TV shows, I occasionally come across the phrase ‘remember this!’ in the context where one character gets wronged by another but couldn’t retaliate right away. How should I interpret this expression? Does it expand into ‘remember what you’ve done because I will get payback’ or it is closely to ‘I will remember this, and will get back at you for it’ or something else completely?

Here is an example:  Person A is standing on a stage and decides to  humorously mock/humiliate someone else in the presence of a huge audience. The person on the receiving end doesn’t want to lash out on the spot but insteads says ‘remember this!’ to person A as he walks down the stage.

Comment: Please add specific examples. I'm asking because it may well be you misunderstood/misremember and/or there are variations like *I'll remember this*. *Occasionally* without being specific is not something we can answer without a lot of speculation.

Comment: @Jan Doggen, actually I think I have also seen ‘I’ll remember this’ variation. I couldn’t find any specific examples right now but I will keep searching. It’s definitely something along the lines of the example I provided. Do you have any knowledge of this kind of expression or similar ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**remember this!**" can be ambiguous without context:

1. "You've done so much bad to my family, mind you, I'll remember this!" - *Means that the speaker isn't going to forget what bad was done and will either take vengeance on or bear it in mind for the future.*
2. "Your father was a fool and did bad things and now he's in jail, so if you don't want to end up like him you had better remember this!" - *Means that the listener had better keep in mind that bad things lead to jail.*
3. "Wash the dishes, take my daughter to kindergarten, pay for the rent. Yeh, I'll remember this!" - *Means that the speaker wants to remember not to forget to do his duties.*